# Adding tiles generated using gdal2tiles to OL3

Tags: javascript, openlayers, gdal2tiles

I had generated tiles using gdal2tiles and had put up all my tile images here http://localhost/maps/.
The XML generated from gdal2tiles

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TileMap version="1.0.0" tilemapservice="http://tms.osgeo.org/1.0.0">
  <Title>J133-12H7h54 tiled.tiff</Title>
  <Abstract></Abstract>
  <SRS>EPSG:3857</SRS>
  <BoundingBox minx="17.34140082382990" miny="60.27332260300220" maxx="17.43368067888432" maxy="60.31931836578014"/>
  <Origin x="17.34140082382990" y="60.27332260300220"/>
  <TileFormat width="256" height="256" mime-type="image/png" extension="png"/>
  <TileSets profile="mercator">
    <TileSet href="1" units-per-pixel="78271.51695000000473" order="1"/>
    <TileSet href="2" units-per-pixel="39135.75847500000236" order="2"/>
    <TileSet href="3" units-per-pixel="19567.87923750000118" order="3"/>
    <TileSet href="4" units-per-pixel="9783.93961875000059" order="4"/>
    <TileSet href="5" units-per-pixel="4891.96980937500030" order="5"/>
    <TileSet href="6" units-per-pixel="2445.98490468750015" order="6"/>
    <TileSet href="7" units-per-pixel="1222.99245234375007" order="7"/>
    <TileSet href="8" units-per-pixel="611.49622617187504" order="8"/>
    <TileSet href="9" units-per-pixel="305.74811308593752" order="9"/>
    <TileSet href="10" units-per-pixel="152.87405654296876" order="10"/>
    <TileSet href="11" units-per-pixel="76.43702827148438" order="11"/>
    <TileSet href="12" units-per-pixel="38.21851413574219" order="12"/>
    <TileSet href="13" units-per-pixel="19.10925706787109" order="13"/>
  </TileSets>
</TileMap>
```

And i had followed code from here https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ol3-dev/FQRup_N1Ess/B7RALoMR4qIJ to use the local tile images to add in OL3. But i couldnot see the tile images for some reason.

Below is the code which i had tried.

```
var resolutions = [ 78271.51695000000473, 39135.75847500000236, 19567.87923750000118, 9783.93961875000059, 4891.96980937500030, 2445.98490468750015, 1222.99245234375007, 611.49622617187504, 305.74811308593752, 152.87405654296876, 76.43702827148438, 38.21851413574219, 19.10925706787109]; 
var extent = [60.27332260300220, 17.34140082382990, 60.31931836578014, 17.43368067888432]; 
var coordSystemCode = 'EPSG:3857'; 
var projectiono = ol.proj.get(coordSystemCode); 
var tms = new ol.layer.Tile({ 
  preload: 1, 
  source: new ol.source.TileImage({ 
            crossOrigin: null, 
            extent: extent, 
            projection: projection,
            tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.TileGrid({ 
                          extent: extent,
                          origin: [extent[0], extent[1]], 
                          resolutions: resolution }), 
   tileUrlFunction: function(coordinate) { 
                      if (coordinate === null) return undefined; 
                      var z = coordinate[0]; 
                      var x = coordinate[1]; 
                      var y = coordinate[2]; 
                      var url = 'http://localhost/maps/'+z+'/'+ x +'/'+y +'.png'; 
                      return url; } }) }); 
   var view = new ol.View({ projection: 'EPSG:3857', center: center, zoom: 2 }); 
   var osm = new ol.layer.Tile({ source: new ol.source.OSM() }); 
   var map = new ol.Map({ 
       layers: [ osm,tms ], 
       renderer: 'canvas', 
       target: 'map', 
        view: view });
```